# Induction 3^n > 5n^2

Tags: analysis

I need to prove that
3^n > 5n^2 using mathematical induction
I have done the first two steps, but I don't understand how to prove that
3^(n+1) > 5(n+1)^2

Comment: Do you mean $3^n > 5^{n^2}$ ? If, yes, then the inequality is false for all $n$.

Comment: $3^{n+1} = 3\times 3^n$ and $5(n+1)^2 = 5n^2 + 10n + 5$.  You know $5n^2 < 3^n$.  What about $10n$ and $5$?

Comment: Please include *all* information.  (You didn't include that $n\in \mathbb N$ or that $n \ge 4$ [the statement is false for $n =1,2,3$])  And when you say "I have done the first two steps" we are going to want to see them.

Comment: The thing is you *USE* $3^n > 5n^2$ to prove $3^{n+1} > 5(n+1)^2$.  So we must use $3^n$ and $5n^2$ somehow.  So we need to put $3^{n+1}$ into terms of $3^n$.  [And $3^{n+1} = 3\times 3^n$.  And we know that $3^n > 5n^2$ so $3\times 3^n > 3\times 5n^2$.   It remains for us to prove that $3\times 5n^2 > 5(n+1)^2$.  Can you take it from there? [Hint:  $5(n+1)^2 = 5n^2 + 10n + 5$ so $3\times 5n^2 > 5n^2+10n + 1 \iff 2\times 5n^2 > 10n + 1$]

Comment: That's where I was stuck. Finally got it. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- let $a_n=\dfrac{3^n}{5n^2}$
- show that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ (it is easier to set for $n\ge 3$)

hint1:

> for that calculate $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

hint2:

> show $\frac{n}{n+1}>\frac 23$ for $n\ge 3$

- then induction hypothesis $a_n>1$ is easily propagated